# Assign pandas values from a merge result

Tags: python, pandas, merge, inner-join

Say I have two DataFrames, where one is conceptually a subset of the other. How can I efficiently transfer data from the subset to the superset? Here is some data to work with:

```
import pandas as pd

sup = pd.DataFrame({'row': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                    'col': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'val': 1.3})
#    col  row  val
# 0    0    0  1.3
# 1    1    0  1.3
# 2    2    0  1.3
# 3    0    1  1.3
# 4    1    1  1.3
# 5    2    1  1.3
# 6    1    2  1.3
# 7    2    2  1.3

sub = pd.DataFrame({'Row': [2, 0, 1], 'Column': [2, 1, 0], 'Value': [1.1, 4.4, 2.4]})
#    Column  Row  Value
# 0       2    2    1.1
# 1       1    0    4.4
# 2       0    1    2.4
```

I know I can efficiently [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two DataFrames:

```
sup.merge(sub, left_on=['row', 'col'], right_on=['Row', 'Column'])
#    col  row  val  Column  Row  Value
# 0    1    0  1.3       1    0    4.4
# 1    0    1  1.3       0    1    2.4
# 2    2    2  1.3       2    2    1.1
```

But how could I overwrite the values in `sup['val']` with those matching from `sub['Value']`? In my real world situation, `sup` is about 40k rows, and `sub` is only 1k rows.

The desired result in this example would be:

```
#    col  row  val
# 0    0    0  1.3
# 1    1    0  4.4
# 2    2    0  1.3
# 3    0    1  2.4
# 4    1    1  1.3
# 5    2    1  1.3
# 6    1    2  1.3
# 7    2    2  1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and change values using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), Also you don't need merge here:

```
sub.rename(columns={'Row':'row', 'Column':'col', 'Value':'val'}, inplace=True)
#alternative sub.columns = sup.columns
sub.set_index(['row','col'], inplace=True)
sup.set_index(['row','col'], inplace=True)
sup.loc[sub.index,:] = sub['val']
sup.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(sup)
   row  col  val
0    0    0  1.3
1    0    1  4.4
2    0    2  1.3
3    1    0  2.4
4    1    1  1.3
5    1    2  1.3
6    2    1  1.3
7    2    2  1.1
```

Comment: With my real-world dataset, I only needed to specify (e.g.) `sup.loc[sub.index, 'val'] = sub['val']`, but otherwise this is a really helpful answer to understand how indexes can be used!